# How to create list from URL assets in Python

Tags: python

I have a local directory reader with list.

```
list_dir = os.listdir(local_dir)
list_dir_up = []
for i in list_dir:
   list_dir_up.append(int(i))

print(list_up_dir)
```

now I want to get data from url.

https://perishablepress.com/wp/wp-content/images/2008/directories/floyd-02.gif

url send like link above.
Is there possible way to get list like local I did?

Answer (score 0):

Attached screenshot suggest you are dealing with Apache-based host. I found [htmllistparse](https://pypi.org/project/htmllistparse/) at PyPI, which is *Python parser for Apache/nginx-style HTML directory listing.* So if I am not mistaken it should do what you want, however I am unable to test it.